# Passing command line arguments to a python script, called from a Makefile

Tags: python, makefile, command-line-arguments, gnu-make

I have just started using GNU's make command to automate things. I ran into a problem and need some help. 
I have a python script (abc.py) which accepts a command line argument with short notation as ("-t") and long notation("--type") and can be run as :

```
python abc.py --type "blah"
```

However, I wish to run this script(abc.py) from a Makefile. So, now my Makefile looks as:

```
command:
    python abc.py
```

I can now execute the code as `make command`, but how do I accept and pass the user input to abc.py?
Hope, the question is well formed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TBH this isn't really what `make` designed to do.  You'd typically get `make` to figure out the parameter programmatically or use different targets for different sets of parameters.  This can be achieved using environment variables.  If you changed your makefile to look like this:

```
command:
    python abc.py ${PARAMS}
```

Your command would then look like this:

```
make command PARAMS='--type "blah"'
```